# Recursion using local variable, which is only visible from one "function-part"

Tags: c, function, variables, recursion, scope

Suppose i have the following function in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(int n);
int main(){
    int num,add;
    printf("Enter a positive integer:\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    add=sum(num);
    printf("sum=%d",add);
}
int sum(int n){
    int temp;
    temp += 2;
    printf("Temp is : %i", temp);
    if(n==0)
       return n;
    else
       return n+sum(n-1);    /*self call  to function sum() */
}
```

My problem is that I only want to do `temp += 2;` in the first level of the loop. So I want it to be local for only the first loop of sum, and not for all the called sum functions in itself. So to make the question a little bit more clear: Is a variable defined in a recursive function only local for the first part of the recursive "tree"? It's hard to explain my problem, so ask if you don't understand please. Thanks!

EDIT: Added the printf in sum. So the output I would like to have is a several times of:
Temp is : 2
Temp is : 2

But what I think that is going to happen is this:

Temp is : 2
Temp is : 4
etc...

EDIT 2: For the people who would like to try the hard code, here it is: (My problem actually is that as soon as the statement `ar_in[i]+ space_fill == lw && used[i] == 0` is true, I want to execute all there is stated after that `if` statement, until `return 1;` and then return all the way back to the function search_combi. Note: the ar_in[] array is an array of several numbers, for example {10,80,70,60,80})

```
bool search_combi(int ar_in[], int index){
    if (ar_in[index] == lw){
        used[index] = 1;
        comb[combcount][0] = index;
        return 1;
    } else{
        tempcomb[0] = index;
        tempcombcount++;
        space_fill = ar_in[index];
        //search right of element
        search_right(index+1, ar_in);
        return 0;
    }

}

int search_right(int start, int ar_in[]){
    int i, j;
    int temp_space_fill = space_fill;
    printf("Tempspace = %i \n", temp_space_fill);
    if(choose == 1) {
        choose = 0;
        return 1;
    }
    if(start == cn){
        return 1;
    }else{
        for(i = start; i < cn; i++){
             space_fill = temp_space_fill;
             if(choose == 1) {
                break;
             }
            if (ar_in[i] + space_fill == lw && used[i] == 0){
                tempcomb[tempcombcount] = i;
                for(j = 0; j <= tempcombcount; j++){
                    comb[combcount][j] = tempcomb[j];
                    used[tempcomb[j]] = 1;
                }
                combcount++;
                memset(tempcomb, 0 , sizeof(tempcomb));
                tempcombcount = 0; 
                space_fill = 0;
                temp_space_fill = 0; 
                choose = 1;             
                return 1;
            } else if (ar_in[i] + space_fill < lw && used[i] == 0){
                space_fill += ar_in[i];
                tempcomb[tempcombcount] = i;
                tempcombcount++;
            }
            search_right(i+1, ar_in);
        }

    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This local variable is not used in your code. So show an example where you indeed need a local variable.

Comment: and `int temp; temp +=2;`  Um. what do you think you're adding `2` *to* ?

Comment: the local variable 'temp' is not initialized to anything.  it is undefined behaviour to perform math using an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is to use a local variable with the static storage duration. At the first recursive call it is equal for example to zero. If it is equal to zero then you set it to some value. All other recursive calls check whether the variable is equal to zero. If not then they do not change it. You need to set again this varaible to zero when the recursion will end.

Here is an example

```
int sum( int n )
{
    static int temp;

    if ( temp == 0 ) temp += 2;

    printf( "Temp is : %i", temp );

    if ( n == 0 )
    {
       return temp = 0;
    }
    else
    {
       return n + sum( n-1 );    /*self call  to function sum() */
    }
}
```

Here is a more interestoing example

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int sum( unsigned int n, char c )
{
    static char dot;

    if ( dot == 0 ) dot += c;

    printf( "%c", c );

    if ( n == 0 )
    {
       return dot = 0;
    }
    else
    {
       return n + sum( n - 1, c );    /*self call  to function sum() */
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%u\n", sum( 10, '.' ) );
    printf( "%u\n", sum( 10, '*' ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
...........55
***********55
```

Comment: Another approach to make a recursive function behave differently on the first (or other) recursions is by passing a parameter called say `level` which you increment for each recursion, eg by recursing with `sum(n-1, level+1);`. (You can also use `level` to limit the recursion depth.) But you might do better calling a first-level function which then calls the recursive function.

Comment: @Weather Vane Strictly speaking it is not a recursion. It is a separate function that calls a recursive function.

Comment: Sorry, @Vlad I thought that is what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are located on stack so in recursive functions every call creates a new one, e.g.

```
void recursion( void )
{
     int depth = 0;
     if( depth < 10 ) {
          depth++;
          recursion();
     }
}
```

will result in an endless loop because every recursive call creates a new `depth` on stack and initializes it with `0`.

You could resolve this by wrapping the actual recursion by sth. like that:

```
 void recursion( void )
 {
     int depth = 0;
     recursion_internal( &depth );
 }

 void recursion_internal( int *depth )
 {
     if( *depth < 10 ) {
          (*depth)++;
          recursion_internal( depth );
     }
 }
```

I hope that a little bit more general example helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you did not understand how recursion actually works. Whatever I understood your question from that I would say that if you want `temp+=2;` to be read only once then declare it below `#include"stdio.h"`

```
<code>
#include"stdio.h"
int temp=0;
temp+=2;
</code>
```

Also to understand recursion you can visit this site : http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/6.RECURSION.html

In this site it uses `System.out.println("To print a text : ");` which is same as

`printf("To print a text : ");` in c.

Hope this be little helpful to you.

Comment: Well I actually understands it, but i'm working at a very complicated recursive function, but thats too long to post it here, so I tried to make a simpler example. If you want to I could post the whole code..